# Hypothetical exploit of answer-accept mechanics for rep gain

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

I hypothesized a possible exploit of the +2 rep gain for accepting answers to get higher rep than one would deserve. It goes like this:

Assume a user has asked `N` questions and accepts `N` answers but through a sequence of downvotes for the poor quality of the questions has been downvoted down to `2*N` rep or less. May the user:

1. Unaccept all `N` answers, losing `2` rep for each of the `N` questions, but at some point midway through being clamped by the 1-rep floor.
2. Reaccept the same `N` answers, gaining a +2 for each accepted answer, thus in the end ending up with rep `2*N+1`, which is more than what the user had previously?

My questions:

- Have I understood the mechanics correctly?
- If so, is this actually exploitable?
- If so, should this loophole be closed?

Comment: A similar problem exists with downvotes but requires the cooperation of other users (or sock puppets, if one is dedicated enough to create a sock puppet and get it downvoting privs).

Comment: Good find. Didn't think of that yet. Luckily the (temporary) post ban will come in fast, since the questions are still low quality. It will not get them very far.

Comment: @PatrickHofman But, assuming the user _did_ get into a situation where `rep <= 2*numAcceptedAnswers`, my hypothetical would _not_ require the creation of new questions; It merely requires being able to unaccept and accept all previously accepted questions. This does not result in any new question being posted, so the temporary post ban cannot prevent this.

Comment: But how much rep would give this then them? 11, 13? Two pitty upvotes will to the same.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: Some people can be incredibly inefficient without realizing it ;P

Comment: @PatrickHofman To put things in perspective, someone who has managed 50 questions without being banned but still ended up with 1 rep (either because one, or all, questions got downvoted into the ground) could leap back to 101 rep free. What's more, he could regenerate like a hydra this rep, even if it is again downvoted from him.

Comment: But I have not seen anyone with tons of downvotes on their question who survive it to their 50th question. I do get your point though, but I don't think it is too much of an issue. There are much easier ways to get rep.

Comment: possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234437/gaming-system-with-accepts and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234279/about-rep-changes-and-gaming-system-using-them

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I'm not sure any of those posts are exactly the "gaming" I'm describing here, but given this "nicael" 's track record I'm probably not the first one to think of this.

Comment: I think [that particular 'sploit got fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123859/159251), @Bolt, unless I misunderstand what you're talking about.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Oh, so it has. I must have missed the memo.

Comment: Yup, @EugenePodskal, I was just talking about the one BoltClock mentioned in [the first comment here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270272/hypothetical-exploit-of-answer-accept-mechanics-for-rep-gain?noredirect=1#comment87738_270272), not the thing the question's about.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Understood, seems that I've just lost the thread of this discussion . Nonetheless, neither first, nor second problem allows dishonest users to get tons of rep.

Comment: I fail to see why people are so hung up on internet 'brownie points' anyway.

Comment: @TheBlueDog: because people like to have someone (or something) tell they've been a good boy. See for instance: [Badges in Social Media: A Social Psychological Perspective](http://goo.gl/7bIFYm)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let's answer a question:

> "How much reputation can dishonest users get using unaccept-accept
> on answers and downvote-undownvote exploits and how difficult would it be for them to exploit it?"

Here are some points to consider:

1. Both exploits will work only with reputation of **1** .
2. Answers unaccept-accept won't yield more than `(numberOfAnswers * 2)`. And data.stackexchange shows that most users obviously have less than hundred questions - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/221688/count-of-users-grouped-by-hundreds-of-their-asked-questions, hence they won't get more than 200 rep.
3. Downvote-undownvote exploit with puppet accounts theoretically can yield much more rep, but it will demand creation of puppet accounts with [at least 125 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), and organization of downvoting-upvoting that won't be caught by current [serial reversing algorithms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

Seems, that not much and not so easy as it appears.

---

So, how much a threat is it to the current reputation system?

In my opinion it is the threat, but at least not the greatest. These two exploits do not allow to get a lot of reputation, while "Fastest gun 1-line answers on obvious duplicates or quick give me the codez questions" and "Minor edits churning" can be exploited to far greater results with minimal to none overall risks.

---

In any case, what can be done to prevent such abuses?

1. Allow negative reputation - [Why does reputation start at 1, and have a lower bound of 1?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1). In its direct form (`user1231234 with -50 reputation`) for good or for bad it  won't probably be implemented. But actual reputation and displayed reputation can differ: count reputation less than 1, but do not display it - show 1 with label visible only to the user, that explains him that he won't get any increase in the reputation, until it is compensated by future upvotes.
2. Make reputation decrease operations done when user had 1 rep irreversible - actual downvote or unaccept can be reverted, but reputation won't change. It is the nearly the same like 1. , but associates negative reputation with post, not with the user itself. And it is more difficult to organize than negative reputation, but it does not have even slight negative connotations like 1 has.

But will it be actually worth the fuss? Who knows.

Comment: Your three caveats to the hypothetical exploit pretty much outweigh any reason to fix it. I don't see any reason to waste time about it.

Answer (score 3):

This would work only with an account with effectively negative reputation, with a lot of poor answered questions. With such poor questions, the question ban is likely, so there won't be much of them. How many reputation points can a user effectively 'gain' with that trick? 10? Maybe 20? It's not a big issue.

If someone care about the reputation enought to make such 'tricks', it could be done with much less effort by improving own questions or producing some reasonable answers.

If someone is lazy and is simply copying assignments, they [usually] don't care about reputation. They simply post until they get blocked.

It even doesn't make life easier for puppet suckers, since accepting an answer requires no reputation and gives quite significant (as for new account) reputation boost.

I don't think it's worth fixing, however, **mass unaccepting** should be something in *some* way visible to moderators, for other reasons (like rage quit detection, or pocket supper detection).

Comment: `pocket supper detection` - I like the idea of pocket supper, but what is it?

Comment: @SamHolder the same as socket pupper, just not to use that S-word