# Remove rep gain for accepted answer

Tags: discussion

I've read many posts concerning accepted answers and I interpret it as something which have good intentions, but sometimes might lead to unwanted behaviour. The problems I've read and experienced are:

1. An accept is usually given to the *quickest* answer, not the best. In other words: people hunting for rep would rather be quick than spend time on making sure the answer is *correct and good*.
2. Getting rep for an accept might shift the *intention* for giving an answer from "Hope I helped!" to "Hope I get something in return!".
3. People who hunt reps might go after those who forgot, or didn't want, to accept their answer, since the questioner is not anonymous.
4. There have been [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270272/hypothetical-exploit-of-answer-accept-mechanics-for-rep-gain) about a small amount of rep farming using this feature.
5. As rep is used as a reward system, there's always that little feeling of disappointment when someone writes "Thanks, it works!" and didn't accept your answer.

---

I believe removing reps for an accepted answer will provide slightly better answers and a slightly friendlier environment. I'm well aware the points I've brought up are not epidemical or even a great issue, but I see small benefits for it being removed.

Comment: Also note that larger communities, such as popular languages in SO, would manage well enough with the loss in rep itself, but smaller communities, such as more obscure tags or smaller sites would suffer quite a bit.  New users can't upvote, so they can't give rep to others, so those people can't get the upvote priv, etc.  A small community literally can't get off the ground without rep from answer acceptance.  And even that aside, many smaller communities would simply lack users with the rep to perform crucial moderation actions if this were changed.

Comment: But, this would make it take even longer for users to gain the privilege to downvote.

Comment: @KevinB And yet it also would make it take even longer for users to gain the privilege to upvote, so there is that.

Comment: Yes, but my argument is just that. Everyone wants reps to gain privileges which triggers those points I mentioned in my post.

Comment: Preferably, if reps for accepted answer was removed, the amount of reps to get privileges could be lowered.

Comment: This comes up repeatedly and it is nonsense.  Actual hard statistics instead of opinionated guesses like this one show that [SO is 86% effective](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306913/what-is-a-solution-to-the-stack-overflow-underdog-effect) at transferring knowledge to programmers that can't solve their problem.  Those statistics are a bit dated and it is probably worse today.  Everything is worse today, you are not helping. Removing the incentive to post answers is not going to make them better.

Comment: @HansPassant I read your link and it was quite interesting. However, I think I made myself misunderstood: I don't think that this is a problem that has to be fixed to make SO good. I'm not saying that the current system makes it hard to get good or friendly answers/comments. I just believe that it might SO slightly better in some regards.

Comment: You rock [the foundations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56810/168269) of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @GertArnold I know the importance of a reward system. It is what drives the community and don't want it to go away. I just believe that we should focus on rewarding things that lead to a better community.

Comment: Sure, I get your point. But this extra rep for accepted answers is pivotal. It adds a competition aspect that motivates people to go the extra mile. That for some people this "extra mile" means being quicker than the rest (not better) is somewhat distorting, but not essential, I think.

Comment: Okay, i can see that. You're saying that even though it do add more sloppier answers it is outweighed by the increase in good answers. Which sounds reasonable and is a good point. It would nice to gather data and compare, because I'm not sure if I agree fully, but maybe that's not plausible/reliable.

Comment: If it were removed, what would replace it for getting users in a new community from 1 to 15 so they can upvote? suggested edits i guess, but that doesn't seem very good.

Comment: @KevinB Well, maybe give a slight boost in reps for your first few upvotes instead? I think that would be a reasonable solution. There are many ways we can reward beginners in a way so that we reward beneficial behavior.

Comment: but, if noone has enough rep to upvote, who upvotes? clearly that's not a problem for SO, but for a new SE site the rep would have to come from somewhere,

Comment: @KevinB People with more than 15 reps. I got upvotes before I got accepted answers.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman and what about, as Servy pointed out, obscure tags? There are places on this site with very little traffic. New users there don't have the voting privilege, and people woth the voting privilege dont necessarily look at obscure tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> An accept is usually given to the *quickest* answer, not the best.

That doesn't match my experience. What typically gets the check mark is either the answer that helped the asker most, or the most upvoted answer. Both are desirable outcomes.

> Getting rep for an accept might shift the intention for giving an answer from "Hope I helped!" to "Hope I get something in return!".

That dynamic is at the core of the entire system (how are votes any different?) and it's not necessarily a bad thing*: a puny check mark in return for helping the asker doesn't sound like too bad a deal.

> People who hunt reps might go after those who forgot, or didn't want, to accept their answer, since the questioner is not anonymous.

That's been an issue in the past - look up discussions around "accept rate". It's manageable though, as are most problems with petty and vindictive users.

> As rep is used as a reward system, there's always that little feeling of disappointment when someone writes "Thanks, it works!" and didn't accept your answer.

True, that happens occasionally. That's a good thing, though: it builds character. It reminds us all that it's ultimately all just a game, and silly rep points are not to be taken too seriously.

I'd argue for the entire check mark system to be abolished, for different reasons: too often, it sends the wrong message to the world ("this is the correct answer"). The rep gain from accepting is the least problematic aspect of it, though.

<sub>* = as long as common sense is applied.</sub>

Comment: My first thought was also to get the check mark system to be abolished, but since that had already been asked and answered I thought I'd begin a discussion around this topic.  Mostly because if the check mark system couldn't be removed removing reps from an accepted answer would be the second best thing. I'm glad you took your time adding interesting points to the discussion. +1