# Disable reputation earned from having an answer accepted

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, accepted-answer

The OP of a question has the ability to mark one of the answers to their question as ["accepted"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). This is a publicly visible signal to everyone else that the answer worked for the OP. However, accepting an answer also gives the author of the answer +15 reputation. There's no clear benefit to the site for users to gain reputation in this way, and should be disabled. The +2 gained by the OP also serves no purpose at that point, and should be disabled as well.

---

### Specific issues that are addressed by this change:

1. Incentive to provide answers that are only useful to the OP.

   Helping the OP is incidental to the goal of building a repository of high quality questions, and reputation gain from helping individual users is the wrong incentive structure for such a goal. In fact, helping the OP *specifically* is more akin to treating the site as a help-desk, which is counter-productive to the goals of the site.
2. Incentive to post [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533) answers.

   Given multiple equivalent answers that solve the OP's problem, they tend to, quite reasonably, accept the first of these answers. This incentivizes users to post answers as soon as possible (FGITW syndrome), which affects the quality of answers. It also makes users less inclined to search for duplicate targets, resulting in common duplicates being answered frequently, which is unhelpful to the site.
3. Comments asking the OP to accept answers.

   By and large, users claim they leave "please accept an answer" comments because they want to educate the OP about how the site works. If this is true, such comments will still be posted in the same quantity. However, circumstantial evidence suggests that reputation gain plays a large role in this. e.g. there's a high correlation between users posting such comments, and the user also having posted an answer to the question they commented on. Also, Meta, which has no reputation gain from accepted answers, almost never gets any "accept this answer" comments.
4. Posting lots of answers to low quality questions.

   Currently, there is no reputation cap on reputation gained from accepted answers. This incentivizes posting lots of answers every day, and posting answers that are helpful only to the OP. This issue would be partially mitigated by subjecting such reputation gain to the daily reputation cap, but that still means it's worthwhile posting a dozen answers per day that solve OPs' problems, without regard to the quality of the question.
5. Reputation gained from accepted answers gives privileges on the site.

   OPs are typically not qualified to judge whether the quality of an answer is up to the site's standards, and they shouldn't be able to grant reputation (and directly, privileges) to users via an accept. OPs should get to pick which answer helped them the most, and let others know that, they just shouldn't be able to confer reputation in this way.

It is unlikely that the proposal will get rid of the abovementioned issues *completely*, but it will hopefully mitigate them to a significant extent.

---

### What is ***not*** proposed:

1. Disabling the accept feature entirely.

   OPs can still publicly indicate which answer they found the most helpful. This proposal doesn't change anything for users other than the asker, and answerer. (Currently, the UI doesn't make it clear what an "accepted" answer means exactly, and improvements can certainly be made in that regard, but that's beyond the scope of this proposal.)
2. Retroactively removing reputation gained from accepted answers.

   Reputation gained from accepts has been earned in good faith, without violating any rules/norms of the site. I don't see that removing the reputation that was gained this way helps the site moving forward.
3. Disabling this network wide.

   I don't know enough about how other sites on the network work to know if this is appropriate for those sites. Several sites haven't even [unpinned accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568), indicating a higher importance for accepted answers than on this site, and reputation gain may well be important/relevant/useful for them.
4. Changing any of the badges related to accepted answers.

   While earning badges is an incentive to act in a particular way, there's no clear evidence that it's anywhere as strong of a motivation as reputation.

---

This idea [has been proposed 6 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327821) and was negatively received, but I'm hoping that the community's opinion on this subject has changed in the interim. E.g., one of the counter-arguments to the old proposal was that the issue of "accept comments" is "manageable", but at least that issue has become bad enough that site moderators were recently motivated to [propose a rule to disallow such comments entirely](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418169).

Please share any feedback on this proposal, particularly the downsides, but also any upsides that I may have missed out.

Comment: _"OPs are typically not qualified to judge whether the quality of an answer is up to the site's standards"_ Neither are many voters. What's the difference?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Users are rep-gated, i.e. they need a minimum amount of rep in order to cast votes, so the hope is that by earning the required rep they learn a bit about how the site works. OPs are not rep-gated at all when it comes to accepting answers, which is a difference.

Comment: Users can earn the vote-up privilege by receiving only two upvotes even if they also receive two downvotes. There is almost zero chance that that's enough to make users "qualified to judge whether the quality of an answer is up to the site's standards".

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Indeed, and I have no objection to raising the necessary rep requirements for casting votes. However, that's well beyond the scope of this proposal. Also, the fact that there are other issues with site mechanics that could/should be fixed isn't an argument for not fixing other aspects (assuming that's what you're implying.)

Comment: I don't think that the shortcomings of the voting system should be used as argument against addressing the shortcomings of the acceptance system, @41686d6564standsw.Palestine. In the larger scheme of things, the whole privilege system needs a substantial rework.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm implying. I just think that the acceptance feature is an important part of the site, and if we keep removing advantages of the accepted answers, at some point, the whole feature will be useless. I do agree that many low-rep OPs do not know much about how the site works, but I disagree that we should keep taking out the few privileges they have over their own posts. What's next? OPs shouldn't be allowed to edit their own posts?

Comment: I don't think this proposal wants (or can lead to) to take out the privileges of the OPs to accept answers to their posts, @41686d6564standsw.Palestine, if I read it correctly, it only proposes to untie it from reputation incentives to address issues that have been plaguing SO for a long time while still preserving it original intent: to indicate that the OP found one of the answers to be the most useful to them, as well as to keep the reigns of that decision in the OP's hands.

Comment: Some arguments read like they also match the bounty system and the additional reputation it can offer. I'm not against some rep tied to the acceptance of an answer, but I would agree with a reduction of the points this offers. Maybe 5 or 2 (like for accepted edits) sounds reasonable.

Comment: @Tom Yes, some of these arguments could possibly be applied to the bounty system as well. The bounty system (like many of the site mechanics) could probably do with some improvements/refinements, but that's also beyond the scope of this proposal. As to the exact rep that an accepted answer confers, any reduction is better than none IMO, and if reducing it from +15 to +2 instead of +0 has popular support, that's a step in the right direction, and better than nothing.

Comment: I don't know about eliminating it entirely, but I second the idea of lowering it to +5 or +2. It is a little odd that an accept grants *more* rep than an upvote, especially since any asker with sufficient rep and experience will usually do both.

Comment: My own two cents: because I have earned the _site analytics_ privilege just recently, I had a look at all the graphs there recently. And honestly, if you look at the number of accept votes versus up or even downvotes, you'd realise that it is just drop in the ocean, I would say.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Yes, that's true, accepts is a small number compared to up/down votes. I'm not sure why that's relevant here. I don't have any issue (at least not as far as this proposal is concerned) with reputation earned via up/down votes, since that's supposed to be representative of quality. I'm claiming that rep earned via accepts is an issue partly because it's *not* representative of quality, but is only representative of utility for a single person.

Answer (score 10):

> There's no clear benefit to the site for users to gain reputation in this way, and should be disabled.

New users do not have the ability to upvote answers. Under your proposal, people answering questions from new users have zero (rep-based) motivation for doing so.

Removing any incentive to answer new users' questions will cause even more of those questions to remain unanswered unless, by some amount of sheer luck, the question manages to earn enough upvotes to give the questioner the ability to vote.

I would suggest calculating the statistics on the number of questions so impacted is necessary before your proposal is given any serious consideration.

Comment: Well, the answers could still get upvotes, just not from the asker. I'm not entirely sure whether that's a good thing or not, but it appears to be an intentional part of the proposal.

Comment: @CrazyChucky My Unsung Hero badge would suggest otherwise.

Comment: Oh believe me, I've got one too. Again, I'm not saying I necessarily *agree* with the proposal, just that I don't think you're pointing out something they didn't intend. They're explicitly trying to reduce the incentive for answering new user's questions unless the answers are likely to be noticed as useful by people other than just the asker.

Comment: @CrazyChucky "Reduce" might be changing it from 15 to 5.   What's proposed is changing it from 15 to 0.

Comment: Personally I think that's probably a better idea too; I commented so on the question above, before noticing someone else had already said it and deleting.

Comment: Yes, this effect is one of the big reasons for the proposal (it's item 1 in fact). I'm hoping that without the incentive to answer such questions (i.e. the kind that only the OP would find useful) these questions *do* go unanswered. As to the exact rep change, if making it +5 instead of +0 gets popular support, I'd be willing to change that. There's already several comment suggesting this, so it does look to be more popular.

Comment: @cigien I don't play FGITW and am not the target of your proposal.  The questions I answer are mostly in a low-visibility tag that very few people have expertise in.   I might consider supporting a proposal that reduces FGITW competition by reducing rewards based on "views" or some other measure of visibility.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding you, but it sounds like you're claiming that this proposal would reduce your motivation to answer questions? If so, then yes, unfortunately this proposal would target users such as yourself. I am hoping that the number of users who provide quality contributions won't reduce substantially as a result of there being less rep to earn, but perhaps I'm being overly optimistic about that. This is valuable feedback, I appreciate it.

Comment: @cigien Hard to say as I already answer questions for far too little rep.... so I'd probably still do it in the near term.  But I can see burnout arriving sooner with zero motivation. And after 5+ years with 0 rep to show for the work I'd done, I'd probably resort to FGITW with no other rep sources.

Comment: @cigien I think Laurel's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419096/1161484) expresses this point a lot more eloquently than I have.  Low-vis tags in niche or new technologies with a small pool of experts will suffer from your proposal.  I recognize there's a FGITW problem with "answer this trivial question for me" in popular tags, but the fix should be targeted to those questions.

Comment: I've left a comment on Laurel's answer asking what exactly the issue is in niche tags. Their answer suggests it would be harder to earn reputation in those tags, which is true. I don't know if their answer is suggesting that it would reduce the motivation of users to post in those tags (but may well be what they mean, since they pointed out the motivation issue on old posts). I don't really have any concrete ideas for how to constrain something like this proposal (or any proposal really) to only specific tags, I'm afraid.

Comment: @cigien Ultimately, the question is "what problem are you trying to solve"?  Is it people gaining too much rep and then abusing it?  How... or is it people posting crappy answers?   Maybe make downvoting answers not cost rep.... THAT I would vote for and would downvote a lot more than I currently do with the pitifully small amount of rep I earn from quality answers that you're trying to take away. :)

Comment: I've listed 5 specific problems in the question that the proposal attempts to solve. I'd be happy to clarify any of them if they're unclear. Also, I would like to stress that I'm not by any means suggesting that this proposal is the *only* way to address these problems, or that the proposal will solve all of them completely. There are certainly plenty of proposals (including not charging rep for downvotes, which has already been proposed IIRC) that would help for each of these problems.

Comment: @cigien 1. If you're sure it's only helpful to the OP, add a close vote reason (we have nonrepro/typo for this purpose). 2 and 4 can be solved by removing the rep penalty for downvoting answers, even if there's some minimum level of curation ability demonstrated before you get the  free pass. 3. can be stopped with a network text based block on the word "accept".  5. You haven't demonstrated there's a problem here. A bigger problem is people who curate but DON'T gain privileges because rep is nearly impossible to come by for people who primarily curate.

Comment: "*the question is "what problem are you trying to solve"?*" mostly about this: [Rule proposal: comments asking for accepts and votes shall no longer be allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418169/2821954), which also was opposed by the community. It might not look so much of a problem on MSO, but it's because [many meta posts related to this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=accept+answer+%3Cdiv%3E&user=&room=197438) were deleted.

Answer (score 7):

This would make the incentive to post FGITW answers stronger than ever while reducing the incentive to answer old questions. Instead of getting 15-25 points for giving the best answer on an old post with an engaged asker, you would get 0-10. Really, except on a very small selection of questions, nobody sees answers on old posts other than the OP. Instead, it would be even more valuable to be the answer that gets the first upvote on a new question, because you'll be at the top when everyone's looking (and voting). The nature of comments would change from asking for accepts to asking for plain old votes.

(For an explanation of why answers to old questions don't get noticed, consider that we have a [dedicated page for new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), but the [view that new answers show up on](https://stackoverflow.com/) is cluttered with every type of activity, especially edits. If you still don't know what I'm talking about, then I have to wonder what tags you're active in that this isn't the case.)

Also, I wonder if the rep cap even has an effect on the posting behavior you're talking about. Most people aren't motivated by gaming the rep cap. They can't be; you need to be getting a lot of reputation each day for that, which the vast majority of users aren't.

Another effect would be that it becomes very hard for niche technologies to get any sort of foothold. If there are a dozen users of a technology and none of them have any rep on SO, then it would be impossible for any reputation to be generated in that tag — or rather it would either require multiple  upvotes from people who don't know the technology or some of the users to be participating outside of the tag that brought them to the site. This ultimately leads to fewer people being able to upvote (much less downvote), and the formula for the site breaks down: good posts do not rise to the top, bad posts do not get pushed to the bottom, and therefore all answers just shuffle around randomly when you view them.

Comment: Re para 1: I don't really see that this proposal would make the FGITW issue *worse*. Yes, the comments may shift from asking for accepts to asking for upvotes, but we have very robust mechanisms to handle users posting the latter kind of comment, as such comments are strictly not allowed. Unlike the former, which is much less clear, as such comments are often posted to "educate" users (or so is claimed).

Comment: Re para 3: I'm not really sure what you mean by "niche technologies getting a foothold". Users can still ask and answer questions in that tag. If you mean this proposal makes it even harder for users who only post in niche tags to earn lots of reputation, then yes, this proposal would have that effect to some extent. I'm not entirely sure that's a major downside though.

Comment: Re para 2: Yes, this won't affect many users. There are only a handful of users who fall in this category. (I won't call it gaming, just users who cross the rep cap because of accepted answers). There's only a small benefit to be had in this regard, I agree.

Comment: This part of your answer *... while reducing the incentive to answer old questions. Instead of 15-25 points ... you would get 0-10.* is quite important. If it's really true that the opportunity to get 15 less rep will reduce many users' motivation to post answers, and these users would otherwise post high quality content, then this is a loss to the site. I'm hoping that the number of such users is quite low. The few users I know in the tag I follow who consistently post good answers wouldn't really care about the minor rep loss, but that may not be representative of most users.

Comment: "an old post with an engaged asker"? There is such a thing? "except on a very small selection of questions, nobody sees answers on old posts other than the OP." Strange how, when I've recently polished up years-old questions with the intent of answering them, someone beat me to the punch a couple of times.

Comment: Answering or even editing a question does put it back on the main page / "top questions", just like asking a new one.

Comment: *If there are a dozen users of a technology and none of them have any rep on SO, then it would be impossible for any reputation to be generated in that tag* Reputation is supposed to act as a gateway into higher levels of privileges, under the expectation that users with higher reputation will have better learned to use the site. If a bunch of new users only ask and answer in a small echo chamber with no outside influence of expected Q/A quality, I can imagine their future contributions from the reputation earned could do more harm than good as perceived by the community at large.

Comment: @vandench But they do have "outside influence" — every post from a new user is supposed to be reviewed by an experienced user (aka someone with 500+ rep who uses the queues). You don't need to understand the technology to review the worst posts: link only answers, requests for resources, etc. But you do need to know the technology to tell the difference between an answer that works and deserves an upvote and one that doesn't.