# Is it a bug that I can gain reputation by unaccepting and reaccepting when starting at 1 reputation?

Tags: bug, reputation, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

I have 1 reputation to start, I previously accepted some answers and gained reputation from that, but I lost that reputation due to downvotes, so I still only have 1 reputation. I unaccept an answer then reaccepted it, now I have 3 reputation. I can unaccept and reaccept multiple answers, now my reputation is equal to the number of reaccepted answers times 2. Is that a bug?

I understand this is how the rules work, but is this way to spontaneously increase reputation supposed to be there? Like is it on purpose that I can game this system to gain reputation and what comes with it? Is it okay that I was at 1 reputation and now am at 5 reputation by simply unaccepting and reaccepting, and feel free to undo that reputation?

I started yesterday and today with 1 reputation and now I have 3 reputation, and did not get this reputation from upvotes so, where else is it coming from? If anyone with 1 and enough questions can go to 5 is that okay? I may be able to hit 7 without an upvote.

Comment: No, it's expected. Accepting an answer gives you 2 reputation. If you unaccept it, you *lose* that reputation.

Comment: Reminder: you were advised that taglines/signatures are not appropriate for content here; please don't use them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history)

Comment: You really think the system is gonna let you farm reputation that way? That is if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: *"I understand it is by like rules but is this for like spontaneous reputation improvement correct to be there?"* I don't understand what this question is trying to ask.

Comment: It's a known non-issue that 1 rep users can repeatedly go above 1 rep after having lost rep back to 1 by unaccepting/reaccepting. This action won't take you any further than 3 total.

Comment: I gained to 5 with it, X E.

Comment: You *aren't* gaming the system. 5 - 2 + 2 - 2 + 2 - 2 ... = 3 or 5 (depending on you end up leaving the answer accepted or not).

Comment: *"I gained to 5 with it, X E."* What is an "X E"? What do you mean by you gained 5 with the "X E"?

Comment: Read like my profile?

Comment: Your profile cannot grant your reputation.

Comment: Not that I gained by X E, I was at 1, unchecked and rechecked and now am at 5, X E.

Comment: So what is an X E? I can't tell you how you have 5 X E's when I don't know what a single X E is. An X E isn't something I've ever encountered on [so].

Comment: X E is defined as an uncertainty sentence, and I was talking about reputation, I now have 5 reputation, X E.

Comment: So you have 5 uncertain reputation? I have no idea what you mean by that. There's no uncertainty with reputation, it's a specific value, and how it changes is well documented (see the duplicate suggestion).

Comment: Please stop ending your posts and sentences with "X E".

Comment: You were on 5 rep for the past month. You didn't gain any reputation by checking and unchecking the accept mark.

Comment: This isn't an answer as the question is still unclear, however: At a best guess you are asking how you gained reputation from unaccepting and reaccepting. Your reputation *cannot* go below 1, and I *assume* you had < 5 reputation. If we assume 1, then as a result you unaccepted the 2 answers -> `MAX(1- (2*2),1) = 1` (If you had `4` then it would be `MAX(4-(2*2),1) = 1`).  Then you accepted 2 answers -> `MAX(1 + (2*2),1) = 5`. How that becomes X E (uncertain) reputation, I have no idea; uncertain reputation doesn't make sense.

Comment: Not uncertain reputation, just how I use programmatic messages?

Comment: "All as per one might be input maybe or might not be input maybe or might be output maybe or might not be output maybe, maybe or maybe not, maybe" (as in your profile) does not make *anything* clearer, nor does writing "X E" as a short-hand for that. By now you should be aware that this use of "X E" is irritating a number of people. Please, please stop it - continuing to do this is basically trolling.

Comment: Does just talking in question help?

Comment: The question is very hard to read, but it's really a duplicate of [Hypothetical exploit of answer-accept mechanics for rep gain](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270272/6083675). So, yes this is known but you can't possibly gain enough reputation from doing this to make it worthwhile instead of spending your time doing literally anything else that would give you reputation. (Especially since you could get a suspension if the mods find your constant unaccepting/accepting disruptive enough.)

Comment: @maybeJosiah - You cannot farm reputation the way you describe. Even if you could, it will take a little more than you accepting answers to your questions, to lift your question ban. Based on your absolute horrible track record, your next question(s), over the next couple 6 months cycle will have to be absolutely amazing to have any chance of getting even close to lifting the question ban so the rate limit isn’t required. There isn’t a path forward to lift your answer ban other than improving your answers and hope they receive legitimate upvotes from legitimate users.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much impossible, I have almost never gotten a legitimate up vote on this site and no matter what I do, probably never will seemingly maybe or maybe not, maybe.

Comment: I *hope* you've not [decided to trade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76989293/is-prestashop-on-in-javascript-synchronous#comment135788639_76989293) "X E" with your "maybe, maybe, maybe not, maybe..." nonsense... That's not ok either, and it **literally** makes no sense.

Comment: There is a minor hack possible with acceptance flags, for a very specific case (which the OP is in). The contributor needs to be at very low rep, and sustaining a downvote storm. In such a case they can un-accept all their accepted answers, wait for the downvote storm to pass, which would take them to 1 rep. Once the storm has died, they can re-accept and get +2 for each one (rep they would have otherwise lost to DVs). I don't personally think this is worth fixing, and I doubt the extra rep would pull a contributor out of a question/answer ban anyway.

Comment: (The situation described in this post is a little different, and I think it is a bug - what is being described is the re-awarding of the +2 rep even though it has already been awarded).

Comment: @halfer - Question bans are not the result of a lack of reputation, so while they could do what you describe, it won’t lift their question ban. Which is entirely based on the quality of their questions.

Answer (score 6):

It was reported as a bug [some time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234437/gaming-system-with-accepts) and deemed too trivial to fix because you really can't gain very much reputation and you have to be on a very low reputation to start with to exploit it.

As explained by [Nick Craver (who worked for Stack Exchange when they wrote their answer)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver)...

> I have 2 options here:
>
> 1. Remove the inherent ability to do this, sacrificing API and timeline stability to do so (since it's just an artifact of how we choose for the system to work)
> 2. Ban the user doing it
>
> If you're curious, I can tell you which is more likely to happen.

So you're going to get banned if you get caught doing this and as Nick said, you

> leave a *very* clear trail of what you're doing

so it would seem unlikely you'd get away with it for long.